# Change font-size with jquery if screen size is mobile size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my web page, I want to change font-size with jquery if screen-size is mobile size.
My code is as follow:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 if(screen.width <= 600){

        $("#para_head").css({"font-size":"12px"});
        $("#para_detail").css({"font-size":"10px"});
}
</script>
<style>
#para_head{
}
#para_detail{
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="para_head">
    Header
</div>
<div id="para_detail">
    Detail
</div>
</body>
```

As above code, I can't change the font-size. Where should i fix this. Any idea pls.

Comment: let it be noted that i upvoted you just so you could upvote all 4 good answers. You can use 30 votes in a day, but you can only accept one answer per question (hover beside answer to the left and a tick mark will appear. Click it, it will turn green. The answerer gets 15 points, you get 2 for accepting. Win-win! Now hop to it! ;) - Rach

Comment: `screen` is not defined. If you used a console, you would have seen that. Finally, it is true that media queries are the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a `CSS` media query rather than jQuery.  You will require a lot of jQuery manipulation if your application is big, it will also be harder to maintain and most importantly it will be heavy on the DOM.

Responsive websites are much easier to achieve with CSS as shown below.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #para_head {
       font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

**Demo (Resize the output pane)**

https://jsfiddle.net/9351yv7j/

As an additional note I would use the kebab style casing for HTML elements, `para-head` rather than `para_head`.

Comment: Noted bro.  Thz for ur advice 

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use CSS?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 #para_head{
  font-size: 12px;
 }
 #para_detail{
  font-size: 10px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="para_head">
  Para Head
</div>
<div id="para_detail">
  Para Detail
</div>
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) but if you prefer a jquery solution see below

```
if ( $(window).width() > 600) {     
  //Add your javascript for large screens here
}
else {

   $("#para_head").css({"font-size":"12px"});
   $("#para_detail").css({"font-size":"10px"});
}
```

Comment: Noted,  thz a lot.